# Ranking Values in .asp using Access

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, ms-access-2007

fairly new to .asp and the boards, so please bear with me.  I am trying to utilize an access DB which stores 24 unique records (baseball teams) with values for TeamName, TeamUID (unique ID), TotalHR, TotalRS, TotalWins and TotalLosses.  I would like to use this table to display where a team ranks in each category.  For example each team has their own page which is based on their TeamUID.  I want to show where they rank (1st through 24th) in each category but cannot figure out how to do that in the page.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you having problem writing an order by query or in displaying the ranking number?

Comment: i can order by any column but wondering how to do that on each individual page ?  i want to call the table on each teams page and show a different rank for each team in each category.  would an array be the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a rank with MS Access, for example:

```
SELECT table1.ANumber, 
      (SELECT count(*) 
       FROM table1 t 
       WHERE t.anumber<=table1.anumber) AS rank
FROM table1
WHERE (((table1.ANumber) Is Not Null))
ORDER BY table1.ANumber;
```

Run against an ADO connection, you can use [GetString](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_getstring.asp) or [GetRows](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_rs_getrows.asp) to assign this to a string or array.

The above example will give a duplicate number where there is a duplicate value for ANumber. For example:

```
ANumber Rank
-1      1
1       7
1       7
1       7
1       7
1       7
1       7
2       11
2       11
```

Comment: is this possible to do for multiple columns in the same table?  I assume ANumber is Wins for example, can I also have a rank for Losses in the same table?

Comment: Where is the table? No, you cannot use the above idea and rank two different columns, however, you can run slightly different sql for each set of data you display, or you can simply loop through an ordered recordset or array ( getrows ) and write a number for the rank in a table cell.